# Is it possible to place a string inside df[ ] in python?

Tags: python, string, arithmetic-expressions

I know this is a bad one. I really want to know if this is possible to do in python so I have two strings with arithmetic equation now I want to place them inside a df[ ]. df is a data frame Is this possible to do?

```
X = "'cars'+'bikes'*'planes'"
```

Now this should be placed like this below

```
X = df['cars']+df['bikes']*df['planes']
```

If possible how to do it?

Comment: what is `df`? Is it pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes df is data frame

Comment: At first you will have to parse the string into operants and operators. Taking into consideration that the quotation marks can contain more than just characters it might not be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you know the consequences of using `eval`.

```py
s =  "'cars'+'bikes'*'planes'"

df['out'] = eval(re.sub(r"([^+\-*\/]+)", r'df[\1]', s))
```

What is does is basically substitutes `df`. It changes `'cars'+'bikes'*'planes'` to `df['cars']+df['bikes']*df['planes']`.
If you don't want to use `eval` you can parse the `column names` and `operands` like

```
columns = re.findall(r"'([^+\-*\/]+)'", s)
operands = re.findall(r'([+\-*\/]+)', s)
```

But in this case, you need to define operate precedence and create a tree to calculate the result.

---

### Update

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

s =  "'cars'+30*'bikes'-'planes'+20"
s2 = re.sub(r"('[^+\-*\/'\d]+')", r'df[\1]', s)

pd.eval(s2)
```

Comment: what if I have s =  "'cars'*30+'bikes'*'planes'+20" how do I avoid adding df to 20 and 30? Is it possible to get s = df['cars']*30+df['bikes']*df['planes']+20 this?

Comment: is there a `*` in between `'bikes''planes'` or it is empty?

Comment: Opps! it got misplaced. It is this s = "'cars'+30*'bikes'-'planes'+20" and excepted output is s = df['cars']+30*df['bikes']-df['planes']+20. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I was about to text that regarding " ' ". It is working fine now Thanks A lotttt brother! you are the best :)

Comment: I have one doubt. So If I conditional/ comparison symbols in it. Will it do the same when I compare it when I tried it was adding to the symbols rather than to the word. This is what I supplied s = "'cars'>2"  s2 = re.sub(r"('[>=<=<>!=^+\-*\/'\d]+')", r'df[\1]', s) and this is What I got  s = "'cars' df[>] 2'

Comment: The `^` symbol should be at the begining like like `r"('[^>=<=<>!=+\-*\/'\d]+')"` it means match everything `except` >=<=<>!=+\-*\/'\d`. If youy know that the column names is alphabetical like `aa` `bb` `aBa` and never like `aa_1` `some_32`, simply use `r"('[A-Za-z]+')"`, it just matches `abcd...zABCD..Z`

Comment: Yes, i got the solution for that in another question Thanks a lot.